# Why "it would be wasteful to use more embedding dimensions than the number of units in the layer that follows the Embedding layer"

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

Quote from "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow, 2nd Edition":

> One-hot encoding followed by a Dense layer (with no activation function and no biases) is equivalent to an Embedding layer. However, the Embedding layer uses way fewer computations (the performance difference becomes clear when the size of the embedding matrix grows). The Dense layer’s weight matrix plays the role of the embedding matrix. For example, using one-hot vectors of size 20 and a Dense layer with 10 units is equivalent to using an Embedding layer with input_dim=20 and output_dim=10. **As a result, it would be wasteful to use more embedding dimensions than the number of units in the layer that follows the Embedding layer.**

What's the reason for "it would be wasteful to use more embedding dimensions than the number of units in the layer that follows the Embedding layer"?

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon the same question, and here is something I managed to come up with. Sorry if there is any mistake.

---

First, consider a simple (Linear) Dense Layer with input_dim=a, output_dim=c. Let's call it `d12`. Ignoring bias for now.

```
a --d12--> c

c_x = d12.weight * a_x
```

It is possible to split this dense layer into 2 dense layers, the first one (`d1`) has input_dim=a, output_dim=b, and the second one (`d2`) has input_dim=b, output_dim=c.

```
a --d1--> b --d2--> c

b_x = d1.weight * a_x
c_x = d2.weight * b_x
(d12.weight = d2.weight * d1.weight)
```

The question here is: whether the split reduces the amount of information. Here we have 2 cases:

- `a*c <= a*b + b*c` (i.e. d12 has less parameter than d1+d2): No information lost, only introducing additional computation.
- `a*c > a*b + b*c` (i.e. d12 has more parameter than d1+d2): Some information is lost. Basically `b` becomes a bottleneck, as in the case of a Encoder-Decoder structure.

Therefore, if in a network, for 2 linear dense layers can be combined into 1 linear dense layer with out losing information, the middle dimension (`b`) is larger than the output dimension (`c`).

[image: cases of splitting dense layer]

---

An Embedding Layer is essentially a (Linear) Dense Layer with input_dim=vocab_len, output_dim=embedding_dim, activation="linear". Thus, if the output_dim of the embedding layer is larger than the Dense layer following it, the embedding layer can be effectively simplified.

[image: embedding as the case]

Answer (score 0):

It's because:

> One-hot encoding followed by a Dense layer (with no activation function and no biases) is equivalent to an Embedding layer.

So if you use a smaller dense layer after the embedding layer, it's like "onehot layer => big pure linear dense layer => small dense layer". The information encoded in the big pure linear layer is lossy compressed in the smaller dense layer without any non-linear gains.

Instead of this non-efficient way, it's better to just use "onehot layer => small dense layer", which is equal to a smaller embedding layer.